# Send php request onclick via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, post

I know this question have been asked alot but none of the answer are related to my case ,I have a button ,onclick it should call a javascript function send it a php variable,and ajax would call a php file via post and send that vriable and the php file updates my table

so here is the onclick event first

```
<button class="button button6 " onclick="incrementclicks('<?php echo $id; ?>');">increment</button>
```

it should send a variable called $id to the javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function incrementclicks(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "increment.php",
            data: "id=" + id,
            type: "POST"
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the php file increment.php (I'm 100% sure it connects to the server just fine )

```
<?php
     require_once 'dbconnect.php';
     $db_handle = new DBController();
     $id=$_POST["id"];
     $q="UPDATE clicks SET linkclicks = linkclicks + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
     $result = mysql_query($q);
?>
```

it doesn't increment, I don't understand what did i do wrong here

Comment: and what happens in page network? what it shows? i  mean developer tools>network

Comment: echo $q in your increment.php and run directly in your mysql(either from cmd or from phpmyadmin). Also check your `linkclicks` is int or not?

Comment: I don't think my php file is being called in the first place ,this is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can debug your code on the php by doing

```
echo $id;
exit();
```

My quess is that your are missing something there..

Comment: I dont think my php file is getting called

Comment: url: "increment.php", is going to call the same domain as the file so if the one is under localhost:8989 and the server is under localhost:5050 is not going to work. Try putting the whole url

Comment: They are on the same domain ,the increment.php works fine on its own ,so I believe the problem is in calling it from the ajax

Comment: How you called the php file on its own with the post data? Have you tried Postman ?

Comment: I did ,incremeted the filed just fine when its on its own ,I dont think the ajax is calling it

Answer (score 0):

Use this method of ajax to check the issue.And if error found check in console for the issue

```
$.ajax({
                url: "increment.php",
                type: "post", //send it through post method
                data: {
                    id:id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                    alert("some error found");
                }
            });
```

NB:Try to add type="button" to your button for not to reload

```
<button class="button button6 " onclick="incrementclicks(5);" type="button">increment</button>
```

Comment: ok worked thank you for the console tip my problem was rather stupid , I just added                                                                                                            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    before my script and it worked ,thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I just want to answer this if anyone have future problems like this

The problem is I forgot to add script src at the beginning

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

after adding this my code worked just fine :)